# Load intrinsic parameters from file [ueye]

Tags: ros, ueye, camera, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I got an issue with loading parameters from a file while starting the ueye-node.
First I configured the parameters from the commandline and than dumped it in a file. I used the following command:

```
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam dump /camera <file-name>
```

I can change this file in an editor and load it back via the *load* command.

So, now my issue. Is there a possibility to store the file in a specific folder so that the node loads these parameters at startup?

When the ueye-node starts, there is a warning saying:

**Failed to load intrinsics for camera from file**

However, I do not know where and in what format the file must be saved.  Does somebody has any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268561/load-intrinsic-parameters-from-file-%5Bueye%5D/) by [matt_do](https://answers.ros.org/users/31551/matt_do/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Parameters (dynamic or not) can be loaded from a file in roslaunch: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam

Camera calibration and intrinsics are separate. The intrinsics are stored in a configurable folder. This is purely used to dewarp the image using nodes like [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) and others. This file is auto-generated with a calibration procedure involving a checkerboard.

See http://wiki.ros.org/ueye#Camera_Calibration

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2017-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matt_do](https://answers.ros.org/users/31551/matt_do/) on 2017-08-11**:
Thank you for your prompt and comprehensible reply. Now, the difference between parameters and intrinsics is crystal clear.